# Cant get Auth token passed into reducer in redux

Tags: react-native, authentication, redux, react-redux

I have my userKey in the 'userLogin' function below, but when i get ready to send the userkey into my reducer, its not there.

I've tried updating my action to wrapping up the setUserId function into 'userLogin', but i keep getting null in my reducer (the actions are triggering, but its not making its way to the reducer. Help please!

action file

```
export const userLogin = userKey => {
    return async dispatch => {

        await AsyncStorage.setItem('userKey', userKey).then(userKey => {
            console.log('userKey')
            console.log(userKey) // have the key here
            dispatch(setUserId(userKey))
        })
    }
}


export const setUserId = userKey => {
    console.log('userKey')
    console.log(userKey) // comes up as Null
    return {
        type: SET_USERID,
        userKey: userKey
    }
}
```

reducer file

```
import { SET_USERID, REMOVE_USERID } from '../actions/actionTypes'

const initialState = {
    userKey: ''
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USERID:
            return {
                ...state,
                userKey: action.userKey
            };
        case REMOVE_USERID:
            return {
                ...state,
                userKey: null
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
export const userLogin = userKey => {
    return async dispatch => {
     try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('userKey', userKey)            
        console.log('userKey')
        console.log(userKey) // have the key here
        dispatch(setUserId(userKey))
     } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
     }
    }
}
```